# uint8_t Array - Data inside memory

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management

I have a question to a behavior I detect with the gdb.

First I compiled this small program with the gcc on a 64bit machine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void fun (uint8_t *ar)
{
   uint8_t i;

   for(i = 0; i<4; i++)
   {
      printf("%i\n",*(&ar[0]+i));
   }
}

int main (void)
{
   uint8_t ar[4];

   ar[0] = 0b11001100;
   ar[1] = 0b10101010;
   ar[2] = 0b01010110;
   ar[3] = 0b00110011;

   fun(ar);

   return 0;
}
```

Then I look with the gdb to the memory of ar:

```
(gdb) p/t ar
$7 = {11001100, 10101010, 1010110, 110011}
(gdb) x ar
0x7fffffffe360: 00110011010101101010101011001100
(gdb) x 0x7fffffffe360
0x7fffffffe360: 00110011010101101010101011001100
(gdb) x 0x7fffffffe361
0x7fffffffe361: 11111111001100110101011010101010
(gdb) x 0x7fffffffe362
0x7fffffffe362: 01111111111111110011001101010110
(gdb) x 0x7fffffffe363
0x7fffffffe363: 00000000011111111111111100110011
```

I saw that the array of `uint8_t` was collect together to an 32 bit field. For the next addresses this will only push to the right.

```
&ar[0] -> {ar[3],ar[2],ar[1],ar[0]}
&ar[1] -> {xxxx,ar[3],ar[2],ar[1]}
&ar[2] -> {xxxx,xxxx,ar[3],ar[2]}
&ar[3] -> {xxxx,xxxx,xxxx,ar[3]}
```

It's a bit strange and I want to know: Why this will happen and can I rely on this behavior? Is this only typically for gcc or is this a handling standard?

Comment: What is the `[1]` in `printf("%i\n",*(&ar[1]+i));` meant to do? It looks wrong to me to shift all the output by 1...

Comment: Yes you're right. It must be ar[0] but it's not important to this example. I only interested to know how the array was put into the memory. ^But I change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gdb, `x`  just prints out whatever is in the memory location, regardless of its type in the C code. You're just getting some defaults (or previously used formats) for the width(4 bytes in your case) and format. 
Do e.g. `x/b ar` to print the location as bytes. and do `help x` for more info.

If you print it as a anything other than a byte, [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your processor will determine how the memory is interpreted though.

Use `p` to take the type into account, as in `p ar`

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with endianness:

In a x64, and every other little-endian machine, the data of value `0x12345678` is put into memory in the form `78 56 34 12`, i. e. with the lowest significant byte first.

The debugger knows that and shows it to you in this way.

Expressed in hex, making your data easier to read, it looks this way:

Your memory is filled with

```
CC AA 56 33 FF 7F 00
```

which makes

- the value at offset 0 `3356AACC`
- the value at offset 1 `FF3356AA`
- the value at offset 2 `7FFF3356`
- the value at offset 3 `007FFF33`